# Why does Flutter app getting slow in live version

Tags: flutter

After update the flutter sdk, the app getting slow after some 6-7 days. We are storing data offline, cache image and audio download option for offline use, but now it is hanging the full app. Right now we are using a function that check 7 days duration, and delete caches, but still the app running slow and sometime hanged.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without seeing your code. This can have many reasons:

- It takes too long to load data from memory
- It takes too long to write data to memory
- There may be a delay in parsing
- There can be a delay in searching and finding the data

You will most likely need to improve one or more of these to make the app stop slowing down.